# Graphic card crashes under load

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I have recently started having a problem with my GIGABYTE GTX 1080 in my 7 year old build. When I play a videogame the monitor sometimes goes black saying there is no HDMI signal and I have to force a reboot. This only happens under load and never while browsing. There are no Application or System events in the Event Viewer at the time of the crash except for the forced reboot I have to make afterwards. I got the GPU-Z log leading to the crash suspecting overheating but that does not seem to be the case. Is there anything useful in the logs I can use to fix the crashing?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) It could be due to insufficient power. A simple thing to do is to try reconnecting the power leads to the card (and the PSU end) in case their contacts have become a bit dirty over time. While you're doing that, inspect them to make sure that they aren't overheating and melting. 2) What is the make and model of the PSU?

Comment: Could be a power supply dying. Temps look okay and power supplies do get to a point where some rails can't supply enough an more. A PSU that is very closely specified could get to a point where it can only just supply enough and any hiccup means that an entire voltage rail could brownout. Drawing 180W from a single 12V rail can be quite demanding.

Comment: The fact that the 8-Pin voltage (bottom left of your image) goes from 11.8, down to 11.7 down to 11.6 makes me very suspicious. The switch mode supplies on your GPU may well be able to take anything from 5V up to 15V but a dip under load does suggest that the PSU simply cannot supply enough power on that connector. That it is different from the PCIe slot voltage (middle row right) shows that the two voltages are likely on different PSU rails and having them be different by that much is not right. As Andrew says, check are that connectors are fitted well and clean. Otherwise replace the PSU.

Comment: 1) I checked, cleaned and reconnected the 8 pin and it looked fine to me 2) It is an even older (>10 years) FSP 550W. Yeah, seems like the PSU is breathing its last(

Comment: Usually, the only things that declines with age in a PSU are the large electrolytic capacitors. If you're comfortable with DIY electronics, check those an replace if necessary.

Comment: I replaced the PSU and the problem is gone. Thanks everyone!